# Some doubts in a part of the proof of Backwards Martingale Convergence Theorem (Jacod-Protter)

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, expected-value, martingales, jensen-inequality

**A USEFUL RESULT (Doob's Upcrossing Inequality)**
 
Let $(X_n)_{\geq0}$ be a submartingale, let $a<b$ and let $U_n$ be the number of upcrossings of $[a,b]$ before time $n$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}\{U_n\}\leq\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbb{E}\{(X_n-a)^{+}\}
$$

---

> **THEOREM (Backwards Martingale Convergence Theorem)**
>   Given a probability space $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$, let $(X_{-n}, \mathcal{F}_{-n})$ be a backwards martingale (hence $\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{-m}\}=X_{-m}$ a.s., with $0\leq n<m$) and $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}=\bigcap\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{-n}$. Then, the sequence $(X_{-n})$ converges a.s. and in $\mathcal{L}^1$ to a limit $X$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (in particular, $X$ is a.s. finite and is integrable)

---

> **A PART OF THE PROOF OF Backwards Martingale Convergence Theorem**
>   Let $(U_{-n})$ be the number of upcrossings of $(X_{-n})_{n\geq0}$ of $[a,b]$ between time $-n$ and $0$. $(U_{-n})$ is increasing as $n$ goes up and so $U(a,b)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} U_{-n}$. By Monotone Convergence Theorem (equality below) and by Doob's Upcrossing Inequality (red inequality below)
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}\{U(a,b)\}&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{U_{-n}\}\\
> &\color{red}{\leq}\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbb{E}\{(X_0-a)^+\}<\infty
> \end{align*}
>   hence $\mathbb{P}\{U(a,b)<\infty\}=1$. With some work one can also show that $X=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{-n}$ exists a.s..
>   At this point, let $\phi(x)=x^+$ which is convex and increasing and $\color{red}{obviously}$ $\color{red}{\phi(X_{-n})}$ $\color{red}{is}$ $\color{red}{integrable}$, all $n$.
>   Then, $\color{red}{Jensen's}$ $\color{red}{inequality}$ $\color{red}{and}$ $\color{red}{\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{-m}\}=X_{-m}}$ $\color{red}{imply}$ $\color{red}{that}$ $\color{red}{X_{-n}^{+}\leq\mathbb{E}\{X_0^+\mid\mathcal{F}_{-n}\}}$, hence $\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}\leq\mathbb{E}\{X_0^+\}$.
>   Finally, Fatou's lemma (first inequality below) and the fact that $X_{-n}^+\geq0$ and $X_{-n}^+\rightarrow X^+$ a.s. yield
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}\{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{-n}^+\}=\mathbb{E}\{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{-n}^+\}=\mathbb{E}\{X^+\}\leq\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}\color{red}{\leq}\mathbb{E}\{X_0^+\}<\infty
> $$

I cannot really understand the four red-colored parts in the proof above.
$\color{red}{1)}$ Why does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{U_{-n}\}
\leq\dfrac{1}{b-a}\mathbb{E}\{(X_0-a)^+\}$ hold true after applying Doob's Upcrossing Inequality? What I would expect is that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{U_{-n}\}
\leq\dfrac{1}{b-a}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{(X_n-a)^+\}$. So, how is $\dfrac{1}{b-a}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{(X_n-a)^+\}$ related to $\dfrac{1}{b-a}\mathbb{E}\{(X_0-a)^+\}$?
$\color{red}{2)}$ Why can one obviously state that $\phi(X_{-n})=(X_{-n})^+$ is integrable (all $n$) (i.e. $\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}<\infty$)?
$\color{red}{3)}$ By Jensen's inequality and $\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{-m}\}=X_{-m}$ I would expect that $(\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}\})^+\leq\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_0^+\mid\mathcal{F}_{-n}\}$ and not that $X_{-n}^+\leq\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_0^+\mid\mathcal{F}_{-n}\}$. Hence, how is $(\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}\})^+$ related to $X_{-n}^+$?
$\color{red}{4)}$ I would expect that, by definition, $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}\leq\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}$ and not that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}\leq\mathbb{E}\{X_{-0}^+\}$. So, how is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{X_{-n}^+\}$ related to $\mathbb{E}\{X_{-0}^+\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\F{\mathscr{F}}$1) There seems to be a typo, i.e. it should be $E((X_0 - a)^+)$ instead of $E((-X_0 - a)^+)$. Note that for any fixed $n \geqslant 1$, $\{X_m \mid -n \leqslant m \leqslant 0\}$ is a submartingale with respect to $\{\F_m \mid -n \leqslant m \leqslant 0\}$, so $X_0$ is the ending term on the right in the submartingale, and Doob's upcrossing inequality yields$$
E(U_{-n}) \leqslant \frac{1}{b - a}E((X_0 - a)^+),
$$
which implies $\lim\limits_{n → ∞} E(U_{-n}) \leqslant \dfrac{1}{b - a}E((X_0 - a)^+) < +∞$.

2) The existence of the conditional expectation $E(X_{-n} \mid \F_{-m})$ implicitly requires that $X_{-n}$ be integrable, so $E(X_{-n}^+) \leqslant E(|X_{-n}|) < +∞$.

3) This is Jensen's inequality for conditional expectation:$$
E(X_0^+ \mid \F_{-n}) = E(φ(X_0) \mid \F_{-n}) \geqslant φ(E(X_0 \mid \F_{-n})) = φ(X_{-n}) = X_{-n}^+.
$$
4) Since the last line implies that $E(X_{-n}^+) \leqslant E(X_0^+)$, then $\inf\limits_{m \geqslant n} E(X_{-m}^+) \leqslant E(X_0^+)$ for any $n \geqslant 0$ and$$
\varliminf_{n → ∞} E(X_{-n}^+) = \lim_{n → ∞} \inf_{m \geqslant n} E(X_{-m}^+) \leqslant E(X_0^+).
$$

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. Points $2)$, $3)$ and $4$ are now extremely clear to me. I have just two doubts about your point $1)$. How can you pass from straight application of Doob's Upcr. Ineq (i.e. $E(U_{-n}) \leqslant \frac{1}{b - a}E((X_{-n} - a)^+)$) to $E(U_{-n}) \leqslant \frac{1}{b - a}E((X_{-0} - a)^+)$ by means of submartingality property of $(X_n)$? Do you condition expectation to get this? Could you explicit this part? Finally, for confirmation, in last line of point $1)$, $\frac{1}{b-a}E((X_0-a)^+)<\infty$ follows from fact that $(X_0-a)^+$ is nonnegative, doesn't it? @Saad

Comment: @Strictly_increasing To clarify, consider a fixed $n$ and define $Y_k=X_{k-n}$, $\mathscr G_k=\mathscr F_{k-n}$ for $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, then $U_{-n}$ is the times of upcrossings of the $\{\mathscr G_k\}$-martingale $\{Y_k\}$ between $Y_0$ and $Y_n$, so$$E(U_{-n})\leqslant \frac1{b-a}E((Y_n-a)^+)=\frac1{b-a}E((X_0-a)^+),$$and $(X_0-a)^+\leqslant|X_0-a|\leqslant|X_0|+|a|$ implies that $E((X_0-a)^+)\leqslant E(|X_0|)+|a|<+∞$.

Comment: Ok as to the integrability part, thank you! However, as to the first part..given that in the text of the question there is not the definition of a process $\{Y_k\}$ such that for a fixed $n$, $Y_k=X_{k-n}$, but only the definition of a process $\{X_{-n}\}$, **following your reasoning** *it is like I should consider (as implicit) that $X_k=X_{k-n}$, for a fixed $n$? This is what you mean? If so, am I allowed to do such a thing "arbitrarily"?* @Saad

Comment: @Strictly_increasing The above definitions of $Y_k$'s and $\mathscr G_k$'s are just for better understanding of what Doob's inequality is saying, so such definitions are purely auxilliary and in no way does it mean that $X_k=X_{k-n}$. Since the inequality $E(U_{-n})\leqslant\cdots$ is about every fixed $n$, so such definitions are legal.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you again for kindness, time and help. Of course I will reward you with bounty :) @Saad

Comment: @Strictly_increasing You're welcome :)